# Disable/Enable Current Wi-Fi Adapter

Tags: c#, windows, wifi, disable

Is there a way to enable/disable system's Wi-Fi adapter in C#? I searched for the solutions but it seems that they are all outdated and not working. Need this for C# application on Windows 10.

Comment: See pinvoke : https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/wlanapi/WlanConnect.html

Comment: @jdweng Does not look like the solution.

Answer (score 0):

This article at CodeProject has some really nifty C# code for accomplishing this:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/HardwareHelper.aspx

In the end you simply make a call such as:

```
HH_Lib hwh = new HH_Lib();

hwh.SetDeviceState("MyDevice", /*Enable*/ true);
hwh.SetDeviceState("MyDevice", /*Disable*/ false);
```